# reCAPTCHA with different domain in Electron/NextJS/ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, electron, next.js, recaptcha

I am developing a service on my domain (https: //mydomain.com)
the service in question accessing a third party service on another domain
(https://anotherdomain.com)
but this other domain uses google recaptcha and I also need to use the same recaptcha on my domain, but I can't use his key loading with my domain, I get the error:
**ERROR for the site owner:
invalid domain for a site key**

is there any way I can load my domain and set the baseURL from another domain?

I'm using **NextJS**, **ReactJS** and **Electron** to load my website

(type: webview )

Comment: You know, the reCAPTCHA is probably there to prevent exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes, but there is the "webview"  (react-native-webview) to do just that on mobile